# How to specify more than one eval_metric for a CatBoostRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

I want to specify more than one evaluation metric for my CatBoostRegressor:

```
model=catboost.CatBoostRegressor(eval_metric=['RMSE', 'MAE', 'R2'])
```

So I can get the results very simple with the `.get_best_score()`  method, but it does not accept the metrics in a list. Is there any way to do this? I could not figure it out nor find an answer. I know that it is easy to solve another way, but I want to know if this can be done with a different input format for the metrics or something or it is not supported. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the list of evaluation metrics to `custom_metric` instead of `eval_metric`:

```py
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# generate the data
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=10, random_state=0)

# split the data
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# fit the model
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=10, custom_metric=['RMSE', 'MAE', 'R2'])
model.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, eval_set=(X_valid, y_valid), silent=True)

# get the best score
print(model.get_best_score())

# {'learn': {
#     'MAE': 42.36387514896515, 
#     'R2': 0.9398622316668792, 
#     'RMSE': 54.878286259899525
#  },
# 'validation': {
#     'MAE': 102.37559908734613, 
#     'R2': 0.6989698975428136, 
#     'RMSE': 134.75006267018009
#  }}
```